# Is there a way to implement the Xorshift32 algorithm in R?

Tags: r, random

First of all I am not a specialist of R at all.
I am looking for a solution of implementing the Xorshift32 algorithm in R, using RNGKind if it's possible.

My final goal is to perform test of randomness on the Xorshift32 algorithm , using this library
https://rdrr.io/cran/CryptRndTest/man/adaptive.chi.square.html

Thanks you in advance for help !

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It would really help if you showed what you have tried so far in terms  of input data, code and expected output. Check out these links for  asking a good question [ask]  and [reprex] for a minimal working example.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an R version of the first C implementation shown in the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xorshift) about the xorshift algorithm:

```r
xorshift32 <- function(x)
{
  x <- as.integer(x)
  x <- bitwXor(bitwShiftL(x, 13), x)
  x <- bitwXor(bitwShiftR(x, 17), x)
  bitwXor(bitwShiftL(x, 5), x)
}

xorshift32(1)
#> [1] 270369
```

However, it would be better to just have the compiled C code called directly via a function in R, created with `Rcpp::cppFunction`:

```
Rcpp::cppFunction("uint32_t xorshift32(uint32_t x){x^=x<<13;x^=x>>17;x^=x<<5;return x;}")

xorshift32(1)
#> [1] 270369
```